# What are the must-have helper classes for a ASP.NET MVC Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper

I want to know the must-have helper classes to make an MVC application as decoupled as possible without being ridiculous. Below I am listing the helper classes available from the NerdDinner.com ASP.net sample application showing off MVC Framework.

- ControllerHelpers.cs
- FileNotFoundResult.cs
- HandleErrorWithELMAHAttribute.cs
- MobileCapableWebFormViewEngine.cs
- PaginatedList.cs
- PhoneValidator.cs
- UrlHelperExtensions.cs
- SessionHelper.cs (not in NerdDinner)

Also I usually include a few htmlHelpers, and for sure Interfaces for my datasources, but that is not a helper I guess.

Thanks.

Comment: This is best as a community wiki question. Mainly because it's a subjective question with no definite answer, and secondly because best practices is regarded as the reason for having community wiki in the first place.

Comment: Hi Dan: I agree with you .  Do you know how to change a question from normal to community link.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a class, but a library. [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) is a must have IMO.